# WSO2 DAS Substring

Tags: wso2, substr, wso2-das, siddhi, wso2-cep

I am currently using Siddhi QL, and i have a simple requirement.
 Input data is given in quote e.g.

> "apple"

and the output would be :

> apple

I have tried using

> `select substr(inputDATA,1,4) as out insert into outputStream;`

Than i am getting error

```
"substr is neither a function nor an aggregated attribute, "
```

However i have tried using JS inside siddhi to substring `

> define function splitFn[JavaScript] return string {}

it but i got :

```
`jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ParserException: <eval>:1:22 Missing

 space after numeric literal var data = [""tempID=1wef"",0]`
```

Do you have any alternative solution ; or am i doing something wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use siddhi function with namespace

```
str:substr(inputDATA,1,4)
```

E.g

```
select str:substr(inputDATA,1,4) as out insert into outputStream;
```

Refer [Siddhi Documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP400/SiddhiQL+Guide+3.0#SiddhiQLGuide3.0-SiddhiExtensions) for further reference.

Comment: Thanks for the input; i had seen the doc but was still not able to figure out the actual method to do it correctly... Thnkx again

Comment: The function should be called in "<namespace>:<function name>(<parameter1>, <parameter2>, ... )" syntext and you can find all extentions at https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP400/Siddhi+Extensions

Comment: Thats good to know; as i have said I have also went through the documentation but couldn't understood what 'namespace' is meant for. I would really helpful if there would be a working example present in doc.